# How to write SQL script to Update on Select Query

Tags: sql

i have below scenario and needs help to write SQLscript.

i have two tables, 
table 1 and table 2.

I want to `UPDATE` `table2.fk_table1_pk` with the value of `table1.table_pk` if `table2.col1 = table1.col1`

can someone help to write sql script for that?

i have tried executing manually, but it take more time.

thanks

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you use sql so below query will help you

```
UPDATE table2 SET fk_table1_pk = table1.table_pk
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.col1 = table1.col1
```

Comment: That is non-standard SQL and we don't yet know which DBMS chintan is actually using.